# Get/extract dynamic text outline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, svg, flash-builder

I am creating an application in flex, i need to create a handwrite effect for text, I need to get the outline for the text in coordinates or vectors using AS3.

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492796/how-can-i-extract-the-outline-of-text-and-export-it-to-svg). As textfields cannot be read usin `readGraphicsData()`. But i cannot create static textfields becuase am using pure Flex here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm no Flex expert (never needed the tool) but I'm aware it allows [using AS3 code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7fff.html). **(1)** So make static textfield by using `var myTxt : TextField = new TextField();`, from there you can addChild to a sprite & `draw` the sprite. Now do usual steps of getting `GraphicsData()` from bitmapData. **(2)** Perhaps consider making animations for each alphabet letter (26 animations) then show animations (of each letter in your `String`) being "written" as animated pen strokes. **(3)** Where's your Question mark?

Comment: @VC.One if you `draw` into a `BitmapData`, the text will be rasterized and the vector outline will be lost. The point of `readGraphicsData()` is to retrieve vector data, which a `BitmapData` does not have. Option 2 is the way to go (post as answer please), because the handwriting animation itself cannot be automated, as the font does not contain information about the construction of each glyph, which makes reasoning about what strokes to make and how to do them pretty much impossible. On the other hand, animating all letters should not take more than a few hours.

Comment: @null good point about rasterization. I was confused by a passing thought to an old technique (actually was directly grabbing bitmapdata of a video via `readGraphicsData()` as security workaround when `bmd.draw(videoObj)` gave issues). On second look, NStream was secretly putting bitmapData of playing video into a Shape via `bitmapFill` (and we simply extract those pixels via  `readGraphicsData()` back into our bitmap object)... I never analysed that **GraphicsData** results, every video pixel could have been a vector stroke for all I know. Asker could investigate with a one-letter test...

Comment: @null regarding my _"every video pixel could have been a vector stroke"_ seems costly compared to a pixel's simple `Xpos, Ypos, Color`, right? I suspect the code lets us work with pixel / bitmapdata code but Flash Player is a vector-based renderer at heart. Maybe all display objects are secretly grab-able vectors . Like I said Asker can investigate this part.

Comment: @VC.One I think there's even an not so secret way by reading the font file directly. After all it's just the vector data that makes up the font. However, if rasterized or vector, the problem is to turn that data into a handwriting animation. This requires domain specific knowledge about the font to be used, what line should be drawn first, second, etc. I still think creating an animation for each letter is the most straightforward, efficient and quickest way to accomplish what's asked for in the question.

Comment: I cant able to create animation for each alphabets , because i need to make animation for my 50 fonts provided and also user upload fonts , so it is not possible